# Unexpected token : Webpack , reactjs and babel

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

I got this error when I write "npm start" but I don't know why it gives me error anyone who knows this problem?

if it for some help I use babel.js react.js webpack.js I got the newest update on them

```
    module: {
          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (/var/www/html/nivus/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:133:13)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nivus@0.1.0 start: `webpack-dev-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the nivus@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

here is my package.json I don't have missed any ,

```
 {
  "name": "nivus",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --progress",
    "build": "webpack --mode production --progress"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/helper-explode-class": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.1",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9"
  }
}
```

here is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.export = {

    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin()
    ]
}
```

Comment: @Idan don't think I have any missing. look the new i update

Comment: omg i am so blind didn't realize that " }, " made so my last " } " in the config didn't close thank you really @Idan

Comment: flagging for closure because typo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react project setup - npm run webpack issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268352/react-project-setup-npm-run-webpack-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token :...

If you get this message during `npm start` it is likely that npm cannot start due to a syntax error in one of the `.json` files.

In this case, the issue is in the webpack.

```
module.export = { 
  module: { loaders: [ { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" } ] 
  }, 
  plugins: [ new HtmlWebpackPlugin() ] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `},` on the line after `module.exports` should not be there.

Comment: yeah i solved it thanks by @idan But you to dude thanks